# Gradle file paths too long for Windows

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

Alright, I've seen similar questions but I have yet to find a satisfying solution to this, so I'm opening a new one. The problem is that Gradle produces insanely long file paths that blow past the 240 path limit on Windows. The problem is, once `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` runs I get errors like this:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-ar: C:/tmp/ATC/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/[redacted]/D_/[redacted]/android/[redacted]_ATC/src/main/jni/__/__/__/__/[redacted]/src/main/jni/__/__/__/__/__/source_code/app/missions/mission_utils/mission_data/mission_difficulty.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/tmp/ATC/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/lib[redacted].a] Error 1
```

I have already changed the `buildDir` of the gradle project to C:/tmp and stripped as much of it as possible. I have also moved the project itself to the root of the drive, as well as enabled Windows 10 long paths, which are the only suggestions I have found. However, looking at the path, it really looks like Gradle turns `..` int `__` instead of turning it into a real path, so the path to the file could just as well be:

`C:/tmp/ATC/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/[redacted]/D_/[redacted]/android/[redacted]_ATC/source_code/app/missions/mission_utils/mission_data/mission_difficulty.o`

Still a string that strikes me as insanely long but it would solve my problem for the time being. Is it possible to convince Gradle to generate these kinds of paths? Is there anything else that I can do? Windows 10 long path support *is* already enabled

Comment: Is there a special task that fails with an error about a too long path? If it is e.g. a JavaExec task this Gradle forum entry could possibly help: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-wildcards-in-javaexec-classpath/8501 If not more details about your project setup and system setup could help. But from this comment it seems it is an known limitation https://discuss.gradle.org/t/filename-too-long-in-windows/9222/2

Comment: @mascha I posted the specific command that fails. Please note that this is an issue with the NDK and not with Java. The class path is not my problem, the problem that I have is that the Android archiver can‘t open the .o files that the compiler produces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows long path support is there (win10, even on Win7) but the tooling is not yet there.

> Still a string that strikes me as insanely long but it would solve my
>   problem for the time being. Is it possible to convince Gradle to
>   generate these kinds of paths?

Not that I know of.  I think the path itself is not an issue it is the prefix that matters, if you use long paths.

> Is there anything else that I can do? Windows 10 long path support is
>   already enabled.

I think Windows 10 long path support will not help in your case.  The issue is that anything that you build with `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` has not been prefixed by `\\?\` which is needed for windows to recognize that it is a long path.

There is even opened [ticket #711](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/711) for your problem.  The solution would be similar as for [clang++](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/478).

### The workarounds that came to me:

It is not a "pure" windows solution.  One would be to use [windows 10 linux subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).  Second option would be to use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and specific for [Gradle](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/gradle).

Comment: WSL was also my idea, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like Android Studio supports remote building and running Android Studio on WSL with a windows based X-Server doesn't work. I guess I'll have to wait until ticket #711 is solved.

Comment: @JustSid ah, that is a pitty :(.  I don't know the tooling that deep to be able to create the patch.  There is a patch ready at llvm.org - https://reviews.llvm.org/rL311382, but you probably need to adjust also `binutils`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'm stuck with working on my slower mac. Oh well, one of these days I'm sure this will be fixed. Thanks for all the help and digging :)

Comment: @JustSid You are welcome.  Thank you too :). I would love to help you more, but apparently even the maintainers are thinking about how to approach it.